# Django register error not fully translated

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, internationalization

Standard error massage during registration is:
"user account with this email already exists."

After I changed LANGUAGE_CODE to 'pl' in settings.py I get:
"Istnieje już user account z tą wartością pola email."

Instead of "user account" should be "konto użytkownika".

Translation mistake is so obvious that I thought that "user account" is somewhere in my project files so I searched my django project and there is no single string in any of my files.

How to fix this translation?
In django I use 'rest_framework' and 'rest_framework_simplejwt'

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

add verbose_name like this:

```
UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
  
  class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'konto użytkownika'
```

**Reason:**

"user account" is made up from class name "UserAccount"

It would be silly to change class name to "KontoUżytkowanika" just to change translation so I go to django files and I found code responsible for putting class name inside error string:

(...)django\conf\locale\pl\LC_MESSAGES\django.po

```
msgid "%(model_name)s with this %(field_label)s already exists."
msgstr "Istnieje już %(model_name)s z tą wartością pola %(field_label)s."
```

(...)django\db\models\fields_*init*_.py

```
@cached_property
def error_messages(self):
    messages = {}
    for c in reversed(self.__class__.__mro__):
        messages.update(getattr(c, "default_error_messages", {}))
    messages.update(self._error_messages or {})
    return messages

    (...)

@total_ordering
class Field(RegisterLookupMixin):
    (...)
    default_error_messages = {
    (...)
    "unique": _("%(model_name)s with this %(field_label)s already exists."),
```

(...)\django\db\models\base.py

```
class Model(metaclass=ModelBase):
(...)

def unique_error_message(self, model_class, unique_check):
    opts = model_class._meta

    params = {
        "model": self,
        "model_class": model_class,
        "model_name": capfirst(opts.verbose_name),
        "unique_check": unique_check,
    }

    # A unique field
    if len(unique_check) == 1:
        field = opts.get_field(unique_check[0])
        params["field_label"] = capfirst(field.verbose_name)
        return ValidationError(
            message=field.error_messages["unique"],
            code="unique",
            params=params,
        )
```